Do rental cars near Gare du Nord have Crit'Air stickers?
When I was in Paris last February, the rental car I got at the airport didn't have a Crit'Air sticker. So I couldn't use the car in Paris.
I have called up car rental companies and they cannot confirm that the cars near Gare du Nord will have the required Crit'Air stickers.
Has anyone rented a car near Gare du Nord station that can confirm that the cars have Crit'Air stickers?

Since it is required to have them to drive in Paris, I would expect the big agencies will have them, but I don't know, last time I rented was before the Crit'air

If February 2024 my rental car was from a big agency and it didn't have it. I had to rent a second car in order to drive in Paris.

The Crit'Air restrictions in Paris apply during weekdays only, between 8h and 20h. You can drive freely during the weekend. But, during the upcoming months, I would not recommend driving there either as there is significant traffic mess due to the Olympics, including closed-off areas and lanes reserved for official vehicles.
Beware, other French urban areas that adhere to the Crit'Air system - or have to, by recent law, enforce more permanent restrictions.

@Fred That's indeed somewhat surprising but unlike CDG, Gare du Nord is inside the restricted area so if it doesn't have the sticker, it means someone else, probably an employee of the car rental companies itself, had to illegally drive into Paris, which would be even more concerning. OTOH, I don't have the feeling enforcement is very active.

maybe you can do without a car within Paris? There are tons of other transport options available, most of them faster, cheaper, and generally more convenient than having your own car.

@Relaxed In talking with Parisians they indicated to me that enforcement was active (maybe not very active) in certain areas. Some of the more affluent areas even use cameras to determine if you have the sticker. And the fine is quite steep, about 300 Euros, hence my concerns.

@njzk2 Normally this is something I would consider, but I will have someone with me who cannot walk very well and doesn't use a wheel chair. So walking a couple of blocks to get to the metro isn't a possibility. I will drop people off, go park the car and then join them later.

@Fred This Parisian doesn't seem to think so ;)
